# Tendency of Schrodinger equation with various well-like potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

In undergraduate quantum physics, we solved Schrodinger equaitons with various well-like potentials, such as **infinite well**, **harmonic** and **linear**.

They have the tendency that---their energy levels get more closely spaced at higher energy as the *bottom* of the potential get *closer*. By closer, I mean that if the one smoothly transforms from infinite well to harmonic potential,
$$
V(x)=0,\;|x|<a\rightarrow V(x)=Ax^2,
$$
he will find out that
$$
E\propto n^2\rightarrow E\propto n.
$$
For linear potential, V(x)=|x|, whose bottom is even sharper and closer than harmonics potential, the energy is given by eq.(8.53) in Griffiths' QM 3rd with $\nu=1;\alpha=1$, 
$$
E\propto n^{2/3}.
$$
My naive guess is that---wells' walls with larger slope will allow more "relaxations" for particles to fool around. One can immediately check this claim by computing the inclination of walls with derivative
$$
V(x)_{\text{infinite well}}'\sim\pm\infty,\; V(x)'_{\text{harmonics}}\sim x,\; V(x)'_{\text{linear}}\sim\pm1.
$$
I'm wondering is there better and more intuitive explanation for this tendency?

Comment: Would the energy levels of hydrogen serve as a counter example?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to derive this scaling using the WKB approximation and the Bohr-Sommerfeld quantization condition. See [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_quantum_theory#One-dimensional_potential:_U.3D0) for derivations corresponding to no potential, the linear potential, and the harmonic oscillator.

Comment: This is also slightly mentioned in griffiths' book. Thanks! The wiki page indeed provides more general derivations.